# How to show and hide something in jQuery using if's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone so I want to show and hide a button using jQuery, but only if a variable is true for example.

Ex:

```
var st1wch1 = false;

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        var st1wch1 = true
        state1_1warrior()
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(st1wch1 == false){
        $("button#choice1").show()
    }
    else if(st1wch1 == true){
         $("button#choice1").hide()   
    }
 })
```

But for some reason it never hides, any ideas??? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is because the if statement only fires once: When the page loads. Not every time you click on `#choice1`. Also, even if it did work like that, every time you click on `#choice1` the variable `st1wch1` is set to true.

Comment: The hiding and showing only happens when the page loads, never again, so what happens when the element is clicked doesn't really matter

Comment: @JamesDouglas even if it were being false, it would not be reactive anyway.

Comment: So, what do you suggest?

Comment: @ajva, you should also be posting the HTML you want to hide.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to do it may be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
       $("button#choice1").toggle()
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The OP should be posting the HTML to make a fix then.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you've implemented to show or hide the element is defined within the document ready event, which is raised before the user has a chance to click on the button and raise the event handler which toggles your global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to hide and show when the element is clicked?

```
$("#choice1").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: only if the variable is true, and by default is false. Then if someone clicks a button the variable will be true, making the button hide.

Comment: I don't think you're getting this, but the variable doesn't matter, what you're describing seems to be just a regular toggle functionality when the button is clicked?

Comment: Then again, when it's hidden, you'll have to use something other than the button to show it again, as you click a button that isn't there

Comment: Ok, what i'm trying to do is for example 4 buttons and each one goes to another function, which has a continue button to come back again to the original one. After that as the user had already clicked that button, i want it to disappear and that's it.

Comment: You can hide and show elements with the methods called the same thing, but I don't really get the logic? The above code would hide the button, but you'd have to show it in some other event handler

Answer (score 0):

After changing the variable, you code does not go through the if else conditions.  Put that show and hide condition inside a function like below

```
function toggleButton(){
    if(st1wch1 == false){
        $("button#choice1").show()
    }
    else if(st1wch1 == true){
        $("button#choice1").hide()   
    }
}
```

and then call this function everytime you change the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

You must place your code inside the click handler.
I think you want to add at least 2 buttons later, and you want to toggle just a part of them or something like this.

```js
var st1wch1 = false;


 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
       if(st1wch1 == false){
         st1wch1 = true;
        $("button#choice1").show()
      }
      else if(st1wch1 == true){
       st1wch1 = false;
       $("button#choice1").hide()   
     } 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="choice1">choice1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use toggle:

```
var st1wch1 = true;
$('#choice1').toggle(condition);
```

Side note: Don't use things like

```
if (st1wch1 === true)
```

> Do:

```
if (st1wch1)
```

> and (for the == false / === false case):

```
if (!st1wch1)
```

Answer (score 0):

document.ready() is only called when the page initially loads, so it evaluates the if/else statement when you load the page and then never again. Clicking the element doesn't rerun the if else statement.

To get the behavior you want you can either do

```
$("#choice1").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

or

```
$("#choice1").click(function(){
   evaluateBoolean();
});

function evaluateBoolean(){
    if(st1wch1 == false){
        $("button#choice1").show()
    }
    else if(st1wch1 == true){
          $("button#choice1").hide()   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

$('#button').toggleClass('hidden', condition);

Created css class with display: none;